# How to set an element as fixed-fullscreen

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

To make it clear, I want to have a full screen header. On dynamic scroll (single or multiple scroll), the whole header should scroll up disappearing as the screen scrolls down. And vise versa, should the user scroll more from the top of the content, the header should scroll down completely full screen.

Can I do this using css? I've seen this design more commonly used on submitted sited at [AWWWARDS.com](http://www.awwwards.com/)

Comment: Do you mean a navigation that change on scrolling? the site like https://medium.com/
check it on single posts.

Comment: At the example you gave the header stays while scrolling and doesn't disappear. Is that what you want?

Comment: @Roysh no, but check this out. this is a site from awwwards.com: http://demo.nrgthemes.com/projects/keenwp/?ref=NRGThemes

Comment: Yes you can design fixed fullscreen

Comment: Yes you could achieve that using JS, but for that add your jsfiddle.

Answer (score 0):

short answer: no. If I understand it well, you want to have a parrallax effect, where one single scroll will scroll to the first anchor point.

For the fullscreen header however use this:

```
<div class="fullscreen">
    <img src="test.jpg">
</div>

<style>
.fullscreen{
width:100%;
height:100vh;
}

.fullscreen img{
min-width:100%;
min-height:100%;
height:100%;
width:100%;
object-fit:cover;
}
</style>
```

Comment: would you be so kind as to give a reason why its not possible?

Comment: it IS possible, just not in css. css is not dynamic, and does not know when you scroll. For that, you need javascript. I could explain a way to do it in JS, but i am no master in javascript, therefor did not show it.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure whether I understood your question correctly. As I understand from the example you provided, that you want your navigation bar to stick to the top of the page as the user scrolls down below it (and stick back to its original position when the user scrolls back up).

There are three ways of doing this:

#### Using Zurb Foudation (easy way)

- Download Zurb Foundation from [here](http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/download.html/) and link it to your website.
- Follow the instructions on [this page](http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/sticky.html) to make a sticky navigation bar.

#### Using JQuery (the best way)

***Make a simple HTML page as follows:***

```
<div class="content-wrapper">
    <div class="header">
        Header
    </div>
    <div class="nav">
        Navigation
    </div>
    <div class="page-content">
        <p>This is random content, I am too lazy to copy and paste lorem ipsum text here... but you get the point. </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

***Define a 'sticky' class in your CSS:***

```
.sticky {
    position: fixed;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 100;
    border-top: 0px;
    }
```

***Add the following JQuery Code:***

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var topStickyNav = $('.nav').offset().top;

var navSticky = function(){
var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();

if (scrollTop > topStickyNav) { 
    $('.nav').addClass('sticky');
} else {
    $('.nav').removeClass('sticky'); 
}
};

navSticky();

$(window).scroll(function() {
    navSticky();
});
});
```

#### The CSS ONLY Way (Not Viable)

- This method only works with Webkit Browsers like Chrome and Safari.
- You need to first enable experimental WebKit features in your browser.

***Now just use the following code in your CSS:***

```
.nav {
    position: -webkit-sticky;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 100;
}
```